# Count the number of appearances of a value in a sorted array in O(log n) complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, complexity-theory

How can I build a function that returns the number of appearances of a given int x in a sorted array, in *O(log n)* complexity?

```
static public int count (int [] a, int x);
```

I'm thinking I might use a binary search to the find the first / last appearance, then continue searching for the last / first appearance, and return the number of instances, but that this is *O(log n)* complexity .

Comment: Indeed. For O(n), you just need to start from the beginning of the array, and continue until you reach a number > x.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea actually works in time O(log n) if you implement it correctly. Do one binary search to find the index i of the first copy of the element, then do another binary search to find the index j of the last copy of the element, then return j - i + 1. Each binary search takes time O(log n), so the total work done is O(log n) + O(log n) = O(log n).

Comment: A binary search won't return you the first or the last index of x. It will give one of the indices of x. But you can just find one, and then use two loops that go in both directions from this index.

Comment: @JBNizet and that's how you get O(N)  =)

Comment: You can do a binary search for x-1 and x+1. Depending on implementation this should do it.

Comment: You get O(N) at worst, and O(log(N)) at best (and in most of the cases, if the numbers are well distributed).

Comment: @JBNizet There's actually a relatively minor modification you can make to binary search to find the first or last copy of an element. Essentially, rather than stopping when you find a copy of the element, you continue to do the binary search, but discard all elements strictly after or strictly before the copy you found. When you're done, you'll be left with the very first or very last copy of the element, depending on which you're looking for.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful this will still give you one of the positions of x - 1, and one of the positions of x + 1, so you'll still need a loop to find the actual boundary.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful is not sure that the array holds the x-1 and x+1 numbers

Comment: You could search for x-1/2 and x+1/2, with your own binary search

Comment: posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution. In a sorted array binarySearch finds the position of a number in log(n) steps. If the number is not present it finds the position that the number should be at, if it were in the array. If you search for x+-1/2 those values will never be in the array, but instead will give you the bounds for x, because it tries to find a value lower/higher than x that cannot exist in an integer array. The comparison automatically converts your ints to double so that everything runs flawlessly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i && i != 50; j++) {
                test.add(i);
            }
        }
        final int[] intTest = new int[test.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < test.size(); j++) {
            final int i = test.get(j);
            intTest[j] = i;
        }
        for(int x = 0; x <= 101; x++) {
            System.out.println(count(intTest,x));
        }
    }
    public static int count (int[] a, int realKey) {
       final double lowKey = realKey-0.5;
       final double highKey = realKey+0.5;
       final int lowerBound = binarySearch(a,0,a.length-1,lowKey);
       final int upperBound = binarySearch(a,0,a.length-1,highKey);
       return upperBound-lowerBound;
    }

   public static int binarySearch(int[] data, int low, int high, double key)
   {
        while(high >= low) {
            final int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            if(data[middle] < key) {
                low = middle + 1;
            }
            if(key < data[middle]) {
                high = middle - 1;
            }
      }
      return high < low?low:high;
   }
}
```

Comment: If you are writing binary search yourself, you better write lower_bound and upper_bound functions(as in cpp), no need for doubles, no restriction to integers

Comment: Will it work correctly for numbers near integer.max_value btw? Not sure if all halfintegers are representable in double

Comment: All ints are representable in double. double is 64 bit and int 32 bit in java. Double has 52 fraction bits that can directly taken from int into double without problems, we are not dividing here so there is no loss of precision. The 1/2 will simply add 1 bit at the end. You could probably use the same method for long value up to 51-52 bits.